# Refactoring if statement in nested for loops

Tags: python, algorithm

I have source code like this one:

```
test_dict = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}

for k, v in test_dict.items():

    # something else...

    for i in v:
        if k == "a":
            x = 100
            y = i
        else:
            x = i
            y = 100
        print(x**2+y)
```

Is there a way to move the `if` statement between the first and second loop?

I would like to avoid the checking for each second loop iteration as the result for each key is the same.

**Update**

What I would like to reach here is a clearest code without repetitions.

I am stuck with the `x` and `y` variables are defined and used in the second `for` loop.

**Update 2**

As some comments pointed out, I abstracted too much the code, sorry for that, I will try to give more details and write a better code example, even if the code is quite big and I am trying to simplify it.

Some info:

1. `test_dict` is created in another part of the code and its leght is not fixed, it could contain several elements
2. as well as the lists inside `test_dict`, they couldn't have the same lenght
3. the elements in the lists are objects
4. `x` and `y` are the input of another function

this, maybe, is a better code example:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class DummyObject:
    id: str = ""
    val: int = 0

test_dict = {
    "ida": [DummyObject("id1", 1), DummyObject("id2", 2)],
    "idb": [DummyObject("id3", 3), DummyObject("id4", 4), DummyObject("id5", 5)],
    # other entries
}


for k, v in test_dict.items():
    
    loop_result = []

    # This is calculate based on other part of the code
    compare_id = function_for_id(k)

    for i in v:
        if DummyObject("idz", 6).id == compare_id:
            x = DummyObject("idz", 6)
            y = i
        else:
            x = i
            y = DummyObject("idz", 6)
        loop_result.append(other_function(x, y))
```

I hope this gives a better idea.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways. What have you tried, and what do you need help with exactly? Check out [ask] for tips.

Comment: Er, I meant to say, multiple ways to refactor this code. Renat's answer does literally what you asked for, but there are other ways that might actually be better (less repetitive, clearer, etc).

Comment: You may have abstracted the code to pinpoint your problem too much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks a bit abstract and I'm not sure what the unseen parts are and how they depend on each other.
Depending on details, you may refactor it to something like this:

```
for k, v in test_dict.items():
    something_else(k, v)

for i in test_dict["a"]:
    x, y = 100, i
    print(x**2+y)

for i in test_dict["b"]:
    x, y = i, 100
    print(x**2+y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a dict to map keys `"a"` and `"b"` to coefficients telling how to combine `100` with `i`:

```py
test_dict = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}
coeff_dict = {"a": (0, 1, 1, 0), "b": (1, 0, 0, 1)}

for k, v in test_dict.items():
    c_100, c_10000, c_i, c_ii = coeff_dict[k]
    for i in v:
        print(c_100 * 100 + c_10000 * 100**2 + c_i * i + c_ii * i**2)
```

Or a variation using exponents instead of coefficients:

```py
test_dict = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}
exp_dict = {"a": (2, 1), "b": (1, 2)}

for k, v in test_dict.items():
    e_100, e_i = exp_dict[k]
    for i in v:
        print(100 ** e_100 + i ** e_i)
```

Or a variation using weird tuple reversals:

```py
test_dict = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}
order_dict = {"a": 1, "b": -1}

for k, v in test_dict.items():
    order = order_dict[k]
    for i in v:
        x, y = (100, i)[::order]
        print(x**2 + y)
```

Or, most generally, a variation using functions:

```py
test_dict = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}
fun_dict = {"a": lambda h, i: h**2 + i,
            "b": lambda h, i: h + i**2}

for k, v in test_dict.items():
    f = fun_dict[k]
    for i in v:
        print(f(100, i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *function object*:

```
def switched(y, x):
    return other_function(x, y)
...
    functor = other_function if DummyObject("idz", 6).id == compare_id else switched
    for i in v:
        functor(DummyObject("idz", i)
```

One straightforward way to move the conditional statement to the outer loop is to split the inner one, duplicating the non-conditional code.
For the first snippet:

```
for k, v in test_dict.items():
    if k == "a":
        for i in v:
            x = 100
            y = i
            print(x**2+y)
    else:
        for i in v:
            x = i
            y = 100
            print(x**2+y)
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than
[match](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements)
or `if`, to remove the conditional you might find that dereferencing a sequence is convenient here.

```
>>> for k, v in test_dict.items():
...     for i in v:
...         j = (k != "a")
...         x = (100, i)[j]
...         y = (i, 100)[j]
...         print(x**2 + y)
... 
10001
10002
10003
116
125
136
```

Alternatively, we might use `{'a': 0, 'b': 1}`
to flexibly map `k` to `j`.
Or even use `j = ord(k) - ord('a')`.

Comment: @KellyBundy, ok, duly amended. I was just looking at that line and thinking an IDE would probably put a red squiggly underline beneath `k`, suggesting a rephrasing of `(_, v)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy, ummm, sorry? I included example output, which is identical to what OP's code prints out. Are you suggesting that subsequent "unseen code" was depending on side effect of assigning `k = 'b'` ? I _guess_ unseen code could be in scope for the question, and to get the refactor to lint clean I'd need to append an ugly `assert k` at the end or otherwise use the value. Not sure that was OP's intent. The pair of alternatives, `dict` or `ord`, were intended to show how to use `k` in "real" code which isn't as simple as the code in the question.

Comment: @KellyBundy, oh, I see where we differ, it's the unseen "in general" part. I was going for exposition with "simplest use of what's clearly an **index**", avoiding tricky expressions, with the thought that "real code most likely will have three or more test_dict entries" so we focus on generalizing there. You had a different interpretation, that's fine. Duly updated. The pair of alternatives still stand at the ready if treating `bool` as `int` isn't the best fit.